# My autoclicker using python3 and pyautogui isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to make a basic auto clicker using python3 pyautogui that allows you to choose the coordinates of the clicking location but it doesn't work the code says no issues but when I run it it gives error messages I only started coding yesterday so it probably some simple fix but I'm at a loss right now I tried to make the code myself so I'm not following a tutorial that has any troubleshooting so I wasn't able to look into that I have it coded where it asks for x cords then y and waits 5 seconds and uses the two inputs to click where the coordinates specify what actually happens is it works until after the 5 seconds where a bunch of stuff pops up and it stops this is the code:

```
import time
import pyautogui


print ('Please enter X coordinate')
x = input()

print('Please enter Y coordinate')
y = input()

print ('Your coordinates are now"',x,'',y,'"clicking  will begin in five seconds')

time.sleep(1)
print('4')
time.sleep(1)
print('3')
time.sleep(1)
print('2')
time.sleep(1)
print('1')
time.sleep(1)
print('clicking has begun')

def click():
    pyautogui.leftClick(x,y)

while True:
    click()
```

Comment: Whoops forgot to mention I'm using mac osx 10.14 Mojave if that's important

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyautogui, but maybe you need to convert coordinates to integers, like so: x = int(input())     , same with  y

Answer (score 1):

When you use :(we know that Python built-in input() function always returns a str(string) class object)

```
x = input() ----> type(x):<class 'str'> string
x =int(input())---->type(x):<class 'int'> integer
```

So for taking integer input we have to type cast those inputs into integers by using Python built-in int() function.(example:`int(input())`

for your code use this:

```
import time
import pyautogui


print ('Please enter X coordinate')
x = int(input())

print('Please enter Y coordinate')
y = int(input())
```